# how to style the collapsed inversed bootstrap navbar lower border color?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Talking about this one.. I can see there are two colours. A darker than BG shade & a lighter than BG shade. how to set those two?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y39IZ.jpg

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please put your code in code snippet tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in bootstrap.css line 4527.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {  
  border-color: #e6776e;
}
```

[image]